# Labeling for Highcharts Funnel Visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to make a guest return funnel that will visualize the number of guests AND the percent of prior visit for 3 categories of consumers: 1 Visit, 2 Visits and 3+ Visits.

```js
$(function () {
    var dataEx = [
                ['1 Visit', 352000],
                ['2 Visits',       88000],
                ['3+ Visits',       42000]
            ],
        len = dataEx.length,
        sum = 0,
        minHeight = 0.05,
        data = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        sum += dataEx[i][1];
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        var t = dataEx[i],
            r = t[1] / sum;
        data[i] = {
            name: t[0],
            y: ( r > minHeight ? t[1]  : sum * minHeight ),
            label: t[1]
        }
    }
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'funnel',
            marginRight: 100,
       
        
          events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle'
            })
          })
        },
        redraw: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle'
            })
          })
        }
      },
        
       },  
      
        title: {
            text: 'Guest Return Funnel',
            x: -50
        },
        tooltip: {
            //enabled: false
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.key  +
                    '</b> = <b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.label, 0) +'</b>';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
            
            
            allowPointSelect: true,
            borderWidth: 12,
            
            animation: {
                duration: 400
            },
            
            
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    
                    connectorWidth:0,
                    distance: 0,
                    
                    formatter: function(){
                      var point = this.point;  
                        console.log(point);
                      return '<b>' + point.name + '</b> (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.label, 0) + ')'; 
                    },                
                    minSize: '10%',
                    color: 'black',
                    softConnector: true
                },
                
                neckWidth: '30%',
              neckHeight: '0%',
              width: '50%',
              height: '110%'
                
                
                //old options are as follows:
                
                //neckWidth: '50%',
                //neckHeight: '50%',
                //-- Other available options
                //height: '200'
                // width: pixels or percent
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Unique users',
            data: data
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Right now I have a funnel in which the number of guests is labeled for each category and it is centered. A data preprocessing algorithm is also being used to visualize possible small values and it will scale it so that it is still present in the result.

I want to add percent of prior visit values to the funnel but I don't know how to do this in the given data format for the series I have used, and I don't think the data preprocessing algorithm will work if I do that.

I also want to change the tooltip so that when I hover over it will display the information like (don't mind that red color).

[image]

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you well, then of course, it is possible using your current data processing algorithm, because the fact that you've already calculated the percents and assign it to `r` variable, just right here in the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var t = dataEx[i],
  r = t[1] / sum;
  data[i] = {
    name: t[0],
    y: (r > minHeight ? t[1] : sum * minHeight)
    label: t[1]
  }
}
```

So you need to round the value and assign it to the new parameter in your `point` object, what can be done by this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var t = dataEx[i],
  r = t[1] / sum;
  data[i] = {
    name: t[0],
    y: (r > minHeight ? t[1] : sum * minHeight),
    percent: Math.round(r * 100),
    label: t[1]
  }
}
```

Then you will be able to access that value in your tooltip and data labels `formatter` functions:

Tooltip formatter:

```
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.key +
          '</b><br/>Percent of Prior Visit: '+ this.point.percent + '%<br/>Guests: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.label, 0);
      }
    },
```

Data labels formatter:

```
      formatter: function() {
        var point = this.point;
        console.log(point);
        return '<b>' + point.name + '</b> (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.label, 0) + ')<br/>' + point.percent + '%';
      }
```

The last thing what you've to do is to align the dataLabels in vertical position, because now they have two lines, so it should be well to center them all. Here is how to achieve that effect:

```
chart: {
  type: 'funnel',
  marginRight: 100,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this;
      Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
        var bBox = p.dataLabel.getBBox()
        p.dataLabel.attr({
          x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
          'text-anchor': 'middle',
          y: p.labelPos.y - (bBox.height / 2)
        })
      })
    },
    redraw: function() {
      var chart = this;
      Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
        p.dataLabel.attr({
          x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
          'text-anchor': 'middle',
          y: p.labelPos.y - (bBox.height / 2)
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/yzx46p38/

Kind regards!